# How to handle real-time api calls on user input using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, user-input

I've been working on a project that shows real-time data using user input. I have two input fields and several view only fields. `Input1` and `Input2` are related field in a way that `Input1`'s api call populates `Input2` and other fields and vice versa `Input2's` api call populates `Input1` and other fields.

The problem is api calls takes variable response time so there are higher chances that user inputs `123` and we get api response for `12` after `123` so the value gets populated in last is for `12` but user input is `123`.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Queue the requests and manage them, before populating check if input is what triggered the request, or debounce the input handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `debounce` to your `input` event. That's a short delay (say 250ms) that only after the last function invocation will actually invoke it. I've used simple implementation from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/ but there are others.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 250) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

function saveInput() {
  console.log('calling api');
}

const processChange = debounce(saveInput, 250);
```

```html
type: <input type="text" oninput="processChange()" />
```